# jQueryUI datepicker 1.12.1 and jQuery 3.5.1 position bug when field is added in floating element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

When using jquery 3.5.1 along with jQuery ui datepicker 1.12.1, it causes a position issue

To create the bug, the input element on which we are attaching the date picker should be inserted inside a fixed element div, once this is done.

You can click on the date picker when scrolling is 0 the date picker opens properly, but now you scroll down to the bottom and now when you will open the datepicker it will not be visible, as its top: position is set as per the scroll so it is not usable when you have scrolled down the date (you can try this on the js file link)

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".date").datepicker();
})
```

```css
body { height: 2000px; }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.min.css">
<div style="position:fixed; width:200px; height:200px; background:#000;">
  <input type="text" class="date">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rajesh520/xy5sv63d/2/

please check the video describing the issue https://youtu.be/RdpzcsSR-B4

Comment: Your fiddle (and the snippet I added to the question from it) both seem to work fine in Chrome and Firefox and do not present the issue you describe. It's possible it's an overflow issue being caused by some CSS in your page which isn't in the example provided.

Comment: Issue is there please check this video https://youtu.be/RdpzcsSR-B4

Comment: Thank you for the video. It seems like it's a jQueryUI bug in Edge only. Their browser support page suggests to send them a report when an issue like this is found: https://jqueryui.com/browser-support/

Comment: sorry it is not a browser related bug, i have tested this in Chrome (the uploaded video is of the chrome) and have tested it in Firefox, Opera and the issue can be sen over there as well

Comment: I'm also using Chrome (on Windows 10) 
and do not see that behaviour: https://i.imgur.com/Tf2RbXh.png

Comment: I am seeign the bug in Chrome and FX both see the video https://youtu.be/huJgmmSdJ18  and have done this test even in the chrom secure mode so other plugin do not interfear in result